# Add 2 images together based on a mask

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Assume I have images A,B and M. The goal is to take image A as a background, and then blend image B with image A but only in the regions of the mask M.

So if a pixel lies in a black region of the mask, that pixel is identical to the same pixel in A. But if a pixel is in a white region of the mask, that resulting pixel should be a blend of the pixels in A and B.

Does OpenCV have a method to achieve this?

Comment: from mask for B you should create a gradient at the mask border and blend according to maskB*B + (1-maskB*A)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. You have 2 images in form of numpy arrays (shape = width,height,3). You find only those pixels that are not black ([0,0,0]) - you get indice (array with indexes) and bend only those.

```
#bcg - background
#mask - mask
#indice - indexes of pixels that are not black

indice =np.where(np.any(mask!=0, axis=2))
bcg.setflags(write=True) # maybe not needed, but sometimes array is write-blocked
bcg[indice]=mask[indice]+bcg[indice] # or (mask[indice]+bcg[indice])/2 - depends on your bending algorithm
```