# Adding Images Together With A Mask

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, style-transfer

So I currently have 2 images below. These were obtained using a neural style transfer network on the foreground and background parts of the image.

[image] [image]

The code used was the following:

```
add = cv2.add(image1, image2)
cv2.imshow('Addition', add)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I have merged them to create the following resultant image:

[image]

However, I want to use the salience mask on the obtained picture. The salience mask is below. I have tried inputting the mask argument to the add function but had no luck. I've tried looking at this article but wasn't able to work out what to do [Add 2 images together based on a mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54152225/add-2-images-together-based-on-a-mask)

[image]

EDIT:

Found the issue was that I was not converting the data types. The updated code is:

```
saliencyMap = cv2.resize(saliencyMap, (384,384))
newmap = saliencyMap.astype(np.uint8)
add = cv2.add(image1, image2, mask=newmap)
cv2.imshow('addition', add)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

However, the resultant image is and I'm not sure why:

[image]

Comment: `add = cv2.add(image1, image2, mask=maskimage)` where maskimage is 8-bits, single channel (grayscale). If that does not do what you want, please clarify how you want the mask to act with respect to the two images. All 3 images must be the same dimensions in width and height and align properly.

Comment: So I tried this. I'm pretty sure the 3 images are the same dimensions and I tried splitting them into 3 different images. However I get the following error (-215:Assertion failed) (mtype == CV_8UC1 || mtype == CV_8SC1) && _mask.sameSize(*psrc1) in function 'cv::arithm_op'.

I have tried looking at the dimensions and reshape everything so they are the same but still have had no luck.

Comment: What are the shapes of each image? Can you post that? The mask image that you posted is not the same dimensions as the other two images as best as I can see. Also post the dtypes.

Comment: I've added what I have found to be the issue but still getting a weird result.

Comment: Do you really want to add them that way? Perhaps multiply one by the mask and multiply the other by the inverse of the mask. Divide each by 255 assuming each image and the masks are 8-bits. Then add them, clip to range 0 to 255 and ensure result is 8 bits. `result=(I1*Mask+I2*(255-Mask))/255` then `result=result.clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)`

Comment: It's not a good way at all really. I'm just trying to find a way to highlight the salient regions without kind of making the image too dark. I want to highlight the regions that are bright in the map for the final image without making the image too dark. Would I need to split the image into the 3 channels first before adding them together?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you might want is to simply resize the two images to the same size and then add them. Then use the mask to do hard light compositing in Python/OpenCV.

img1:

[image]

img2:

[image]

mask (saliency):

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image 1
img1 = cv2.imread('img1.png')
hh, ww = img1.shape[:2]

# read image 2 and resize to same size as img1
img2 = cv2.imread('img2.png')
img2 = cv2.resize(img2, (ww,hh))

# read saliency mask as grayscale and resize to same size as img1
mask = cv2.imread('mask.png')
mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
mask = cv2.resize(mask, (ww,hh))

# add img1 and img2
img12 = cv2.add(img1, img2)

# get mean of mask and shift mean to mid-gray
# desirable for hard light compositing
# add bias as needed
mean = np.mean(mask)
bias = -32
shift = 128 - mean + bias
mask = cv2.add(mask, shift)
mask = cv2.merge([mask,mask,mask])

# threshold mask at mid gray and convert to 3 channels
# (needed to use as src < 0.5 "if" condition in hard light)
thresh = cv2.threshold(mask, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# do hard light composite of img12 and mask
# see CSS specs at https://www.w3.org/TR/compositing-1/#blendinghardlight
img12f = img12.astype(np.uint8)/255
maskf =  mask.astype(np.uint8)/255
threshf =  thresh.astype(np.uint8)/255
threshf_inv = 1 - threshf
low = 2.0 * img12f * maskf
high = 1 - 2.0 * (1-img12f) * (1-maskf)
result = ( 255 * (low * threshf_inv + high * threshf) ).clip(0, 255).astype(np.uint8)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('img12_hardlight.png', result)

# show results
cv2.imshow('img12', img12)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This is absolutely amazing! I love this approach and never knew you could do this. If I do multiple different pictures would I need to change the bias value? I'm planning on doing this approach for different content and style images and using the map to filter everything. Furthermore, instead of make it lighter, is there a way to emphasize the colour of the eyes instead of making them white?

Comment: You might. It depends upon how the combined image looks and more importantly how the saliency looks. In principle, the saliency should have equal dark and light so that the average value is mid-gray. But this turned out to be slightly too dark for this image and my preference, so I added a bias. But I have only tried with your one image. Once you try more, you will get a better idea what is needed.

Comment: Hardlight composite brightens where the mask is bright and darkens where the mask is dark.

Comment: Does this mean that for each image I will need to add my own bias? Will there be a way to automatically increase the brightness for each salience map?

Comment: I have included code to normalize the saliency by adjusting the mean to mid-gray already. But that was not completely adequate for my taste so I added a bias. You will have to test with other images. I cannot say how robust that is.

Comment: If you need it brighter just increase the bias.

Comment: That's totally fine and makes sense with the bias. So with the salience map, are the eyes that you obtained brighter because of the higher brightness of the salience map? I've been trying to find a way to increase the "colour" of the original image. I wanted to use the salience mask to in essence emphasize the colours in the areas already if that makes sense?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235365/discussion-between-nhyi-and-fmw42).

Comment: So I've tried to implement the code that you did and the mask and the result is still just coming up as a black image and i'm not sure why?

Comment: Post the images you are currently trying to use and I will examine. Did you use my code exactly or did you make changes? What version of Python?  What version of OpenCV?

Comment: I managed to work out where I was going wrong since I was not changing the salience map to numbers between 0 and 255 and instead it was numbers between 0-1 since it was normalized. You mentioned before that a good way to emphasize the regions of salience was to look at HSV and splitting up the image. I've attempted my own way of doing this but the resultant image doesn't have any colour.